# Iterate ArrayList returned by Java extension function in XSLT(Saxon)

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I have a program to perform XML mapping using XSLT. I'm using Saxon-HE-9.7 library for this. I'm also using reflexive extension functions in XSLT.

The XSLT calls a java function that returns `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0" xmlns:SQLService="com.db.SQLService"  xmlns:ArrayList="java:java.util.ArrayList" xmlns:HashMap="java.util.HashMap" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:variable name="city">Texas</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="query" select="'Select name, emp_id from employee where city = ?'" />
<xsl:variable name="list" select="SQLService:executeQueryMultiResult($query, $city)" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <xsl:for-each select="abc/company[@type='product']">
            <employee>
                <xsl:attribute name="details">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$list" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </employee>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </test>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting only sinlge record in the list which is the last record of the list returned by executeQueryMultiResult.

I want to store and iterate all the elements of the list?

Comment: Try  <xsl:value-of select="$list" />

Comment: @AjeetSingh tried, its not working.

Comment: Does HE support reflexive extension functions? I though they are only supported in the commercial PE and EE editions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm a bit surprised that when you iterate over `abc/company[@type='product']`, the body of the `xsl:for-each` doesn't depend in any way on the current selected `company`. This means that each iteration of this loop will produce exactly the same output.

Under the default Java-to-XPath conversions, the `ArrayList` should be converted to an XPath sequence, but the java Maps will not be converted to XPath maps; they need to be accessed as external objects.

See what `count($list)` returns and check that it matches your expectations.

**LATER**

I am unable to reproduce the problem. I tested it like this:

```
public void testListOfMaps() {
        try {
            Processor p = new Processor(true);

            XsltCompiler c = p.newXsltCompiler();
            String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                    "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"3.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\n" +
                    "    xmlns:jf=\"java:s9apitest.TestReflexionHelper\">\n" +
                    "    <xsl:output method=\"text\" />\n" +
                    "    <xsl:template name='main'>\n" +
                    "        <xsl:variable name=\"theList\" select=\"jf:getListOfMaps('Weds', 'Wednesday')\" />\n" +
                    "        <xsl:value-of select=\"count($theList)\" />\n" +
                    "        <xsl:value-of select=\"Q{java:java.util.Map}get($theList[1], 'Weds')\" />\n" +
                    "    </xsl:template>\n" +
                    "</xsl:stylesheet>";
            XsltTransformer t = c.compile(new StreamSource(new StringReader(s))).load();
            StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
            Serializer ser = p.newSerializer(out);
            t.setDestination(ser);
            t.setInitialTemplate(new QName("main"));
            t.transform();
            assertTrue(out.toString().equals("2Wednesday"));
        } catch (SaxonApiException e1) {
            fail(e1.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

where the extension function jf:getListOfMaps() is:

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> getListOfMaps(String x, String y) {
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("Mon", "Monday");
        m.put("Tues", "Tuesday");
        m.put(x, y);
        Map<String, String> n = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("Jan", "January");
        m.put("Feb", "February");
        List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(m);
        list.add(n);
        return list;
    }
```

The test demonstrates that Saxon is behaving according to the spec: the Java List of Maps is converted to an XPath sequence of external objects, where the external object is a wrapper around the Java Map that allows use of the underlying Java methods.

I ran this on Saxon 9.9 (9.7 is no longer supported).

I suggest you try and produce a repro that simplifies the problem by replacing your extension function with a dummy stub with the same signature that anyone can run for testing.

I also suggest you tell us exactly what your environment is. I'm a bit puzzled that you say you are using Saxon-HE, because Saxon-HE doesn't support reflexive extension functions.

Comment: count($list) returns 1, while the query returns 8 records.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Actually, the problem is with my ExtensionFunction implementation class. I have reposted the question in seperate thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474503/how-to-support-returning-arraylist-in-extensionfunction-saxon-he-9-7